# How to add a reserved word for closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Reserved words such as `fill` and `stroke` never get renamed.

Is there a way to add to this list?

(This is so that a common property name which is actually used by the browser is not renamed. Adding something to the externs file would be my preferred option.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't reserved words, but are external types. They are not renamed because they are specified in an extern file. Creating your own extern file and including it in your compilation is how you accomplish this.

See http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2013/09/12/how-to-write-closure-compiler-extern-files-part-1-the-basics/